# Parallax: getting parallax events in webpage

Tags: ios, web-applications, parallax

How can I receive parallax events in javascript on a web page when it is served to an iPhone?  I checked out github.com's 404 page and it is responding to movements using the accelerometer.  Just try going to github.com/f7fu3f73fh39f8h3f93fh398h (or any made up page) and check out the cool parallax animation they're doing.

I looked at the source code and wasn't able to see anything special they are doing to get the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are just using [Plax](https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax)

It appears from the plax [example page](http://projects.cameronmcefee.com/plax-demo/) that the accelerometer stuff is handled by that plugin.

They are only including jquery and plax in that page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#plax-sphere-1').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40})
    $('#plax-logo').plaxify({"xRange":20,"yRange":20})
    $('#plax-sphere-2').plaxify({"xRange":10,"yRange":10})
    $('#plax-sphere-3').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40,"invert":true})
    $.plax.enable()
  })
</script>
```

And then in plax.js `lines 209-243`

```
// Determine if the device has an accelerometer
//
// returns true if the browser has window.DeviceMotionEvent (mobile)
function moveable(){
  return (ignoreMoveable===true) ? false : window.DeviceOrientationEvent !== undefined;
}

// The values pulled from the gyroscope of a motion device.
//
// Returns an object literal with x and y as options.
function valuesFromMotion(e) {
  x = e.gamma;
  y = e.beta;

  // Swap x and y in Landscape orientation
  if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
    var a = x;
    x = y;
    y = a;
  }

  // Invert x and y in upsidedown orientations
  if (window.orientation < 0) {
    x = -x;
    y = -y;
  }

  motionStartX = (motionStartX === null) ? x : motionStartX;
  motionStartY = (motionStartY === null) ? y : motionStartY;

  return {
    x: x - motionStartX,
    y: y - motionStartY
  };
}
```